# If f is in Schwartz Space, then derivative is in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, schwartz-space

In Folland's Real Analysis chapter 8.1, there is a remark about Schwarz Space $S$: ''It is an important observation that if $f\in S$
, then $∂^αf\in L^p$
for all α
and all $p \in [1,∞].$
Indeed, $|∂^αf(x)|≤C_N(1+|x|)^{−N}$
for all N
, and $(1+|x|)^{−N}∈L^p$
for $N>n/p$
by Corollary 2.52'' The corollary 2.52 states that if $C,c$ are constants and B={$x\in R^n:|x|<c$} the following statements hold (a.)$|f| \leq C|x|^{-a}$ for $a<n$, then $f \in L^1(B)$ also (b.)$|f| \leq C|x|^{-a}$ for $n<a$, then $f \in L^1(B^c).$ I'm trying to use the corollary rigorously to see that result, but it isn't obvious to me how to apply the corollary as it separates the cases $a<n$ and $a>n$.  I don't understand why we are just taking the case $N>n/p$ to conclude that $∂^αf(x) \in L^p$. Can someone clarify it?

Comment: The bound on $\partial^\alpha f$ holds for all $N$. Hence you are free to choose $N$ as large as you wish.

Comment: Unlike $|x|^{-a}$, $(1+|x|)^{-a}$ is bounded on B. You should think about which part of corollary 2.52 is then needed

Comment: I think I got it. It holds for all N. So, in this situation, the ball itself doesn't matter anymore, but if we want $ ∂^{\alpha}f $ to be in $L^p$ we need the case $N>n/p$. I have one more question in mind now, where does this n come from?